# How to correctly update entity using ORM?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

In Spring JPA, I often see such an implementation of entity update:

```
    @Transactional
    public User updateUser(Long userId, String newName, String newEmail) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User not found"));
        user.setName(newName);
        user.setEmail(newEmail);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Here, we fetch the entity using a SELECT statement and then update it.

Another solution is to update the entity directly:

```
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(Long userId, String newName, String newEmail) {
        int updatedRows = userRepository.updateEmailAndName(userId, newName, newEmail);
        if (updatedRows == 0) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }
```

repository code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update User u set u.name = ?2, u.email = ?3 where u.id = ?1")
    int updateEmailAndName(Long id, String newName, String newEmail);
}
```

So, my question is, isn't the first solution an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not an anti-pattern. Both approaches are correct and dependent on context and code style. Normally the first one is most used because of code readability and is more suitable for testing purposes.

If you use the second one, there will be some cases in which you will need `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)` to persist your changes for subsequence operations. You can learn more about it [HERE](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation).

So, use the best approach according to your needs and team standards.